# MongoDB - How to use setParameter inside a configuration file

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to set a custom value for the logLevel parameter to my MongoDB installation. The standard way to do it seems to pass a --setParameter argument to the mongod.exe executable.

But I read the [Configuration File Options](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/) page, and it indicates that it is possible to [include the setParameter](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#setParameter) within a configuration file.

What's the syntax in this case?

Comment: I can't test right it right now but I am pretty sure it's just a case of adding `logLevel=n` to the `mongodb.conf`. Needs MongoDb `v2.4` or above

Comment: Trying logLevel=0 in the config file results in my service not starting... I'm assuming this is because of a syntax error.

Comment: Oh, I'm on v2.2.3. That's probably why I can't set the logLevel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of MongoDB 2.4, there are now version-specific online manuals for MongoDB.  If you look at the navigation at the top left of the page, you should see a dropdown with available manual versions (eg. "2.4 (current)" or "2.2").  The default manual matches the current stable production release.

The [`setParameter`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod--setParameter) configuration syntax is new to 2.4 (and noted as such in the 2.4 manual).

The historical syntax for setting logLevel/verbosity is to use an increasing number of `v`s (for verbosity, aka [--verbose](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod--verbose)).  So `v` is loglevel 1, `vv` is loglevel 2, and so on.

This config setting will work in [MongoDB 2.2](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod--verbose) and older versions as well as [MongoDB 2.4](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod--verbose):

```
// Set verbosity to logLevel 3:
vvv = true
```

In general you won't want to set a logLevel higher than 1 unless trying to collect information for troubleshooting purposes.  The normal level of logging verboseness is `0`; higher levels can generate a *lot* of logging details.